# Where in the debian source package do I specifiy where the program should be installed?

Tags: source-packages

Currently my program installs to /usr/bin or whatever and I need to change it to /opt/appname. Where do I specify that in the debian source package?

Rasmus

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

If there are files that need to be installed into your package but your standard **make install** won't do it, put the filenames and destinations into an `install` file. They are installed by `dh_install`.You should first check there is not a more specific tool to use. For example, documents should be in the `docs` file and not in this one.

This install file has one line per file installed, with the name of the file (relative to the top build directory) then a space then the installation directory (relative to the install directory). One example of where this is used is if a binary `src/bar` is left uninstalled; the install file might look like:

```
src/bar usr/bin
```

This means when this package is installed, there will be an executable command `/usr/bin/bar`.

Alternatively, this install can have the name of the file only without the installation directory when the relative directory path does not change. This format is usually used for a large package that splits the output of its build into multiple binary packages using package-1.install, package-2.install, etc.

So the only thing you need to do is to create a file named `debian/my_package.install` (replace my_package with the actual name of your package) with the following line:

```
path/to/your/program /opt/appname
```

[Source](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#install)